# Laravel 4 : How to retrieve data in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, one-to-many

(See codes below)

I have two models User and Messages. I want to take 10 messages-*with their associated sender name*-based on each of the inputted conversation id and reverse the data. I have already succeeded in getting the messages but couldn't scale it down to 10 messages each conversation/with their associated sender name.

1. I have tried this to return the messages data with the users data but either I don't know how to access the sender's name or it doesn't return the associated user :

   ```
   $allMessages = Messages::with('User')->whereIn('conv_id',$conv_id);
   ```
2. I have also tried this to return 10 messages but it returns 10 messages based on all the messages it got instead of based on each conversation.

   ```
   $allMessages = Messages::whereIn('conv_id',$conv_id)->take(10);
   ```

How do I get 10 messages based on the id of each conversation together with the messages' associated sender name? Bonus points for improvement of code. Thank you in advance!

---

**User model**

```
public function messages(){
    return $this->hasMany('Messages');
}
```

**Messages model**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $timestamps = Input::get('from'); //timestamp of latest message
        $conv_id = Input::get('conv_id'); //array of conversation ids
        $allMessages = Messages::whereIn('conv_id',$conv_id);
        if(is_null($timestamps)){
           $messages = $allMessages->orderBy('created_at','desc');
        }else{
           asort($timestamps);
           $messages = $allMessages->where('created_at','>',end($timestamps));
        }
        return $messages->get()->reverse();
    }
```

---

**Migrations**

**Messages table**

```
Schema::create('messages', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('conv_id');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**User table**

```
Schema::create('users',function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password',100);
            $table->string('name',150);
            $table->string('usertype',50);
            $table->boolean('block');
            $table->string('remember_token',100);
            $table->timestamp('lastlogin_at');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

---

**EDIT : var_dump preview result of WereWolf's answer in chrome**

```
0: {id:37, user_id:1, conv_id:2, body:damn mate, created_at:2014-06-20 00:55:32,…}
1: {id:38, user_id:1, conv_id:2, body:hello, created_at:2014-06-20 02:18:21,…}
2: {id:39, user_id:1, conv_id:2, body:dude, created_at:2014-06-20 02:20:10,…}
3: {id:40, user_id:1, conv_id:2, body:test, created_at:2014-06-20 06:52:37,…}
4: {id:67, user_id:1, conv_id:2, body:haha, created_at:2014-06-21 01:25:56,…}
5: {id:68, user_id:1, conv_id:2, body:hey, created_at:2014-06-21 01:26:14, updated_at:2014-06-21 01:26:14,…}
6: {id:69, user_id:1, conv_id:1, body:testa, created_at:2014-06-21 01:27:02,…}
7: {id:70, user_id:1, conv_id:1, body:testser, created_at:2014-06-21 01:27:32,…}
8: {id:115, user_id:1, conv_id:2, body:haha, created_at:2014-06-21 02:45:06,…}
9: {id:116, user_id:1, conv_id:2, body:test, created_at:2014-06-21 02:57:03,…}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
$allMessages = Messages::with('user')
                       ->where('conv_id', $conv_id)
                       ->take(10)
                       ->get();
```

This will return a collection of `Messages` model so you need to loop like:

```
@foreach($allMessages as $message)
    {{ $message->user->name }}
    {{ $message->body }}
@endforeach
```

Also, you may use:

```
// Get the first message and then user->name
$allMessages->first()->user->name;

// Get the second message and then user->name
$allMessages->get(1)->user->name;
```

Comment: and how do I access the user's name? I can't seem to find it in the var_dump object.

Comment: `$allMessages->first()->user->name`

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I noticed that u used where() instead of whereIn(). Is that a typo or I should really use where? My conv_id is an array of conversation ids, btw.

Comment: You should use `where`.

Comment: If `$conv_id` is an array of multiple `conv_id`s then you should use `whereIn`, otherwise use `where`, Welcome :-)

Comment: Alright I'm still trying it out. Will accept this answer if all goes well.

Comment: I tried and it did work partly. Another part which is still problematic is that instead of getting 10 messages for each conversation, it gets at most, a total of 10 messages when matched with 2 conversation ids. I would like it to get 10 messages for each conversation, which would make at most, a total of 20 messages retrieved for 2 conversation ids. How do I do that?

Comment: You provided only one `conv_id` in `where` clause, isn't it ?

Comment: Nope, I had two conv_ids in an array. I have edited the question. You can see the result of my var_dump in the edited part. As you can see, it took the last 10 messages of total messages of both conv_ids. I need it to take the last 10 messages of each matched conv_id

Comment: This is the sql generated by your code, btw : `select * from 'messages' where 'conv_id' in (2, 1) order by 'created_at' desc limit 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function PurchaseReport () {

            $heartsPurReport = DB::table('users')

                        ->join('heartz_payment', 'users.id', '=', 'heartz_payment.user_id')
                        ->join('heartz_transaction', 'users.id', '=', 'heartz_transaction.user_id')
                        ->select('users.username', 'users.email', 'heartz_payment.heartz', 'heartz_payment.transaction_id', 'heartz_payment.order_id', 'heartz_payment.created_at', 'heartz_payment.status',  'heartz_payment.amount', 'heartz_transaction.event')->paginate(20);
```

//dd(json_encode($heartsPurReport));

```
                        return view('Reports.Heartz.Purchase')->with('heartz',  $heartsPurReport);                          
    }
```

// in view use foreach loop and use the following for pagination outside foreach loop

```
                       {!! $consumption->render() !!}
```